# How to get the process ID of a created process in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Maybe I'm just missing something obvious in the System.Process API (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process), but it doesn't appear to support getting the raw PID of a process created. The API usually returns a ProcessHandle which can be used easily enough, but this doesn't appear to fulfill a deployment need I have.

I have a case where I want to spawn a long-running process, log the PID it's using, and be able to automatically come back at a later time (days, weeks, months) and kill the old process and re-start with a new process. I'm sure there are several ways to do this auto-deploy-and-restart, but PIDs seemed like the simplest way to do so without too much platform-dependent code.

I'm open to other suggestions about my underlying problem, but it seems odd to me that I can't find any direct PID references (or a way to convert to them) in the process API. This seems like an oversight of the API.

Comment: Can you use the [`unix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.0.1/docs/System-Posix-Process.html) package instead of `process`?

Comment: ...or [`Win32`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.2.2.0/docs/System-Win32-Process.html). The general point being that the OS-specific APIs are generally more powerful than the cross-platform ones, since cross-platform ones can only support things that all OSs support.

Comment: True, OS-specific APIs are generally more powerful. But, it's a little annoying when _one_ thing is stopping your code from being fully portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some example code:

```
import System.Process
import System.Process.Internals

-- | returns Just pid or Nothing if process has already exited
getPid ph = withProcessHandle ph go
  where
    go ph_ = case ph_ of
               OpenHandle x   -> return $ Just x
               ClosedHandle _ -> return Nothing

main = do
  (_,_,_,ph) <- createProcess $ shell "echo $$"
  getPid ph >>= print
```

Note: I haven't tested this under Windows, but it works on OSX and, presumably, Linux.

For Windows, the [Win32 package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.3.0.2) has a `getProcessId` function in the module `System.Win32.Process`, and according to code I've read, this should work:

```
import System.Win32.Process (getProcessId)

main = do
    (_,_,_,ph) <- createProcess $ shell "echo $$"
    pid <- withProcessHandle ph go
    print pid

  where go (OpenHandle x)   = fmap Just $ getProcessId x 
        go (ClosedHandle _) = return Nothing
```

The code I am basing this on is the code for `interruptProcessGroupOf` [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/src/System-Process.html#interruptProcessGroupOf)

Comment: This seems to do the trick in a reasonable way (verified under Windows, too), without really breaking the abstraction (IMO). This also looks similar to this old mailing list post: https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2012-October/104028.html

Comment: Upon further review, I'm not so sure of the results. I modified this to $ shell "notepad" to more easily find the PID in Task Manager. Looks like I'm getting different PIDs for both this and asjo's suggestion, neither of which match.

Comment: Scratch that, I had confused myself. I was looking for notepad's PID, but I forgot this was being shell-invoked, so I really should have been looking for the shell process ID, which matches asjo's result. withProcessHandle results don't seem to (directly) match the PID result on Windows; I'm getting hex values, but they're too low to match the child processes.

Comment: Answer updated with potential Win32 solution. Let me know if it compiles.

Comment: Yep, that was what I tried as well, based on digging into asjo's link. That seems to be correct for Windows; I'm still a bit confused about what the values are that the **OpenHandle x -> return $ Just x** line is returning. The hex code results that come back don't seem to match up with anything, so I'm guessing it's reporting something different than a PID.

Comment: What kind of values are you getting? It's some represetnation of a Windows `ProcHandle`, e.g. see around line 55 of `cbits/runProcess.c` in the `process` package [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/src/cbits/runProcess.c)

Comment: (Not sure how to format this) My results:

2884  -- actual Windows process ID
Just 0x00000000000001a0  -- 416d, not sure what this is

Using a tweaked version of your getPid:

module Main
  where

import System.Process
import System.Process.Internals
import System.Win32.Process (getProcessId)

getPid ph = withProcessHandle ph go
  where
    go ph_ = case ph_ of
               OpenHandle x   -> do
                  getProcessId x >>= (putStrLn . show)  -- actual process ID on Windows
                  return $ Just x  -- actual process ID on Linux
               ClosedHandle _ -> return Nothing

Comment: Ah... I just realized, the funny hex value is probably the IntPtr for the handle, offset to the local process memory. It seems to compile as a GHC.Ptr.Ptr.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `interruptProcessGroupOf` in `System.Process` calls either `System.Posix.Process.getProcessGroupIDOf` (POSIX/not Windows) or `System.Win32.Process.getProcessId` (Windows) to get the pid: http://git.haskell.org/packages/process.git/blob/HEAD:/System/Process.hs

Comment: Could you describe the difference between `getProcessGroupID` and `getProcessID` in `System.Posix.Process`?

Comment: No. I guess one works for POSIX systems, the other for Windows systems. I guess that System.Process could be changed to factor out the code for getting the pid from interruptProcessGroupOf into a function that code using System.Process could use.

Comment: I was a little bit unclear. Both of the functions I mentioned are in the `System.Posix.Process` module, different from the `getProcessId` in the Windows module. (Even spelled differently: `ID` vs `Id`.) I *think* it has something to do with getting the PID of the current process vs getting the PID of the parent process, but I don't understand the details.

Comment: I noticed that, too. There seems to be better support for getting parent process IDs than the actual spawned child processes.

Comment: I played with user5402's suggestion a bit and found some unexpected behavior with it. Tentatively, this seems like the correct answer, but I'll wait to verify later today when I have access to both Windows and Linux systems. The extra due diligence seems necessary, due to the oddness I was seeing with the other results.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails,

```
import System.Process.Internals
```

and then dig inside the [`ProcessHandle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/src/System-Process-Internals.html#ProcessHandle)  abstraction. You probably want to extract the `PHANDLE` from the `MVar`.

Note that this breaks the abstraction layer, which is meant to make the code portable across OSs. Use it with extreme care, and be prepared for it to break in new versions of the library.